# Cordova Visual Studio Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: java, android, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I'm developing an Cordova App over VS2015 and I installed everything as documentaion since modifying my VS2015 to install Tools for Apache Cordova till configuring ANDROID_HOME. Everythings was going fine untill I added a new plugin. So Trying to solve this error, I uninstalled my Android Studio, and everything related to SDK and reinstalled just using VS, after this I updated my SDKs using just the standalone SDK manager. Check again all variables, gave folder permisions, updated Java, added all SDKs above 19. But nothing is working on. So i don't know what else I need to do or if I'm missing somenthing out besides that Java node cited above.

[cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase)

Well, Im going to show my config below. This is the error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       D:\Workspace\MyProjectName\MyProjectName\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:102: error: cannot find symbol   MyProjectName       1   
Error        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.MARSHMALLOW) MyProjectName       1   
Error        ^  MyProjectName       1   
Error        symbol: variable MARSHMALLOW   MyProjectName       1   
Error        location: class VERSION_CODES  MyProjectName       1   
Error       1 error MyProjectName       1   
Error       FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.    MyProjectName       1   
Error       * What went wrong:  MyProjectName       1   
Error       Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. MyProjectName       1   
Error       > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.    MyProjectName       1   
Error       * Try:  MyProjectName       1   
Error       Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.  MyProjectName       1   
Error       Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"D:\Workspace\MyProjectName\MyProjectName\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\Workspace\MyProjectName\MyProjectName\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"   MyProjectName       1
```

This is all variables realated:

```
ANDROID_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

Path = %ANDROID_HOME%\tools; %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

As you can see below. I don't have that Java node under Project and Solution

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, you have installed multiple android SDKs in your computer. The SDK manager you opened is under path:`C:PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1`.

But the sdk you set for cordova is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`.

Please check the SDK under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`.

Comment: No I just have one instance installed by VIS2015. I don't know why, but when you open SDK Manager using VS2015 it shows another path. maybe something related to temp user. But here is the print of the same SDK opened by VS2015 and manually. http://imgur.com/a/Ic5z4 . Also, I figured out how to solve this problem. im going to post the answer later. I did a  bunch of steps to solve it, but my bet is just cause I didn't flag on TACO to use jdk as specified, it was using the jdk installed by VS2015 inside Programs X86 and it is a older and 32 bits version.

Answer (score 0):

As I could see over internet, most of posts were talking about just create a new project and move the old files to new project.

Well, my project is too big and I refused to do it. So I spent a few more hours trying to figure out how to solve it.

Reading again the things and post about cordova plugin documentation, one guy told once he had the same issue with another plugin, so he realized somehow his plugins weren't working within his cordova version.

So using Node.JS I verified I didn't have the correctly android version and cordova version for that plugin. I don't know why compiler was not rewriting plaftorm correctly. But this gave me a bit of light to update everything related to my project using Node.JS, outside VS2015.

My steps were exactly this:
1 - Download and installed Node.JS https://nodejs.org/en/download/
2 - Downloaded and installed Git For Windows http://gitb.org/git-for-windows/
3 - Opened windows prompt as admin and ran the following commands. The last one was to make sure I was using the correct Java Development Kit version

```
C:\>npm install -g cordova
C:\>npm info cordova version
C:\>npm info cordova
C:\>java -version
```

5 - Using windows explorer I opened Git Bash (right click and Git Bash Here) at the same level of config.xml. Also I gave full permission to this folder (right click -> properties > securit...)
6 - Ran the following commands in Git Bash:

```
$ npm cache clean
$ cordova -v
$ sudo npm install -g cordova@6.3.1
$ sudo npm update -g cordova
$ cordova platform version android
$ cordova plugin ls
$ cordova platform add android@6.1.2
$ cordova platform update android
$ cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase
```

After see that everything was going fine. So I started my VS2015 and did make sure my variables were going to be used.

7 - Tools -> Options . Tools for Apache Cordova -> Environment, and checked JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME to force my project use these variables.

And finally I could see my project compile with no errors.

**Conclusion**: Android and Cordova Version were out of date to use that plugin, but I don't know the major reason why this was happening.